How to close the trackchanges window
I have a trackchanges window containing my professor's comments in my overleaf document. It suddenly popped up. I can't understand how to close the window, however I previously closed the window several times.
Somebody, please guide me.
I have attached the image.
Zulfi

click on the green review button at the top to toggle it on or off

you have 61 errrors in that document best to fix those before looking at professors comments

You can also click on the little > arrow in the middle of the track changes/comments section. @DavidCarlisle it could be 60 warnings and 1 error, then the icon also turns red.

In your screenshot, do you see that at the top, in the middle, the 'Review' tab is green, while other tabs (Share, Submit, History) are black? You must click on the 'Review' tab. It will become dark and the review pane will close.

